# Set paging file to none in cli

Tags: windows, paging, wmic

I'm trying to disable paging file with WMIC or other commands,

[image]

I found [multiple links](https://garvis.ca/2018/02/07/change-the-page-in-command-line/) online but it's all about changing the location.

How do I disable it in cli?

Comment: Check [Page file manipulation using PowerShell](https://www.mitchyb.com/posts/page-file-manipulation-using-powershell/) article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved, the syntax is a little bit confusing:

```
wmic pagefileset where name="C:\\pagefile.sys" delete
```